# (Unity 3D) How to move a GameObject incrementally to set position once its trigger has been clicked? Using Vector3.MoveTowards (Open to other Methods)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, move

[image]
Just for clarity - Here is an image for reference, I want to click on any of the smaller cubes at the bottom so that the corresponding larger cube moves left or right till it's centred in the screen.

So this is the script I'm using, and my issue is that once I've clicked my trigger it only moves a fraction of the total distance, the MoveTowards function does work the way I want, the only issue is that I have to click on my trigger/s multiple times before it reaches it's set destination, I would like this to work so that I only have to click the trigger once and it will smoothly move to it's set destination incrementally instead of based off a certain amount of time between position because the starting position will constantly be changing.

From what I've researched I think I'll need a coroutine, I'm just wondering if there's a simpler way to do this as it feels like I'm only one or 2 steps off my goal here.

```cs
public class MoveBoxes : MonoBehaviour
{
    RayCast rayCast; 
    Camera cam;     
    public LayerMask mask;     
    private float speed = 7500f;

    public Vector3 initialPosition; 
    public Vector3 positionOne; 
    public Vector3 positionTwo; 
    public Vector3 positionThree; 
    public Vector3 positionFour; 
    public Vector3 positionFive; 
    public Vector3 positionSix; 
    public Vector3 positionSeven; 
    public Vector3 positionEight; 
    public Vector3 positionNine; 
    public Vector3 positionTen; 
    public Vector3 positionEleven; 
    public Vector3 positionTwelve; 
    public Vector3 positionThirteen; 
    public Vector3 positionFourteen;

    public Vector3 tempPosition;

    void Awake() { 
    
        cam = Camera.main;
        
        initialPosition = new Vector3(-28000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionOne = new Vector3(37000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionTwo = new Vector3(27000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionThree = new Vector3(17000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionFour = new Vector3(7000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionFive = new Vector3(-3000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionSix = new Vector3(-13000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionSeven = new Vector3(-23000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionEight = new Vector3(-33000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionNine = new Vector3(-43000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionTen = new Vector3(-53000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionEleven = new Vector3(-63000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionTwelve = new Vector3(-73000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionThirteen = new Vector3(-83000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        positionFourteen = new Vector3(-93000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f);
        
        tempPosition = transform.position;
        
    Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
    float move = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    bool hitTarget = false;
    
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
    
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 15000, mask))
        {
            
            if (hit.collider.tag == "1stBox")
                do
                {
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionOne, move);
    
                    Debug.Log(transform.position);
                }
                while (hitTarget == true);
    
            if (hit.collider.tag == "2ndBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionTwo, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "3rdBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionThree, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "4thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionFour, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "5thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionFive, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "6thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionSix, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "7thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionSeven, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "8thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionEight, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "9thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionNine, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "10thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionTen, move);
                
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "11thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionEleven, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "12thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionTwelve, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "13thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionThirteen, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
            if (hit.collider.tag == "14thBox")
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionFourteen, move);
    
                Debug.Log(transform.position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked into a bunch of different ways on how to do this, most results I get involve using a character, my project does not involve a character at this point in the game, nor does it need a rigid body, these GameObjects will eventually be triggers for further events.

I need my Parent-GameObject to move based off of framerate/increments of space rather than based off amount of time. as the whole object shifts, the starting position will be constantly changing also.

The do/while statement in the code can be removed, at the moment it's ineffective, I was trying to use this method to loop the function in my script, with the goal to make a single mouse click act asif it's continuously being clicked.
At the moment when I click on a trigger it will only move a fraction of the distance towards the target destination.

Comment: Just as a side note: Instead of having 14(+) different tags and 14(+) according target positions ... why not rather have a dedicated component on your click targets where you can also store and adjust the according targetPosition along ;) Your update metho would shrink down to one single check

Answer (score 2):

If I may, I looked at first reducing the amount of code to make things clearer, and then secondly, allowing the object to steadily move towards a destination. Naturally, as with almost all coding solutions, this is just one out of many ways to accomplish this.

The reason you need to trigger the code multiple times is because `MoveTowards` simply calculated a single value that represents a new position along the path from origin to destination. It is not a repeating function, it does one calculation and then stops. The method needs to be called every frame so that you can get a smooth movement from one position to the next. Your origin will change every frame as you get closer to the destination, but your destination point will stay the same. The movement step is also calculated by `Time.deltaTime` so that the movement is smooth independent of frame rate.

The resulting code looks like this:

```cs
public class MoveBoxes : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 7500f;

    // Set default position values.
    [SerializeField] private List<Vector3> _positions = new()
    {
        new Vector3 ( -28000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( 37000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( 27000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( 17000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( 7000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -3000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -13000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -23000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -33000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -43000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -53000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -63000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -73000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -83000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f ),
        new Vector3 ( -93000.20f, -102.18f, -3919.06f )
    };

    // Set default tag names.
    [SerializeField] private List<string> _tags = new()
    {
        "1stBox",
        "2ndBox",
        "3rdBox",
        "4thBox",
        "5thBox",
        "6thBox",
        "7thBox",
        "8thBox",
        "9thBox",
        "10thBox",
        "11thBox",
        "12thBox",
        "13thBox",
        "14thBox"
    };

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _mask;

    [SerializeField] private Camera _cam;

    public bool moving { get; private set; }
    public int destinationIndex { get; private set; }


    private void Awake ( )
    {
        _cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update ( )
    {
        if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown ( 0 ) )
        {
            if ( Physics.Raycast ( _cam.ScreenPointToRay ( Input.mousePosition ), out var hit, 15000, _mask ) )
            {
                for ( int i = 0; i < _tags.Count; i++ )
                    if ( hit.collider.CompareTag ( _tags [ i ] ) )
                    {
                        // If a Box has been hit, set this as the new destination.
                        destinationIndex = i + 1;
                        moving = true;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        // if 'moving' is true, move slightly closer to destination every frame.
        if ( moving )
        {
            transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards ( 
                transform.localPosition, 
                _positions[ destinationIndex ], 
                speed * Time.deltaTime );

            // When two Vector3 items are compared with ==, they are determined to be
            // equal if they're 'approximately' the same, and very close to each other.
            if ( transform.localPosition == _positions [ destinationIndex ] )
                moving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the docs for the [Vector3.==](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) operator. As described, the two vectors are considered equal, as long as they're close enough to be considered the same.

[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: @MickyD my intention was detailed in the comments (move slowly towards destination every frame), but you’re right, I could repeat that outside of the code.

Comment: @MickyD and you too for the feedback =)

Comment: Hey there thanks for taking the time to reply,
I tried this script out, but unfortunately my GameObject moves the wrong way when i click on one of the triggers and instead of it only moving along the x axis, it seems to be enlarging my GameObjects

Comment: @EskiStoj that's odd, as there's no "scaling" code present. Is it a visual aspect because of the way you're camera is viewing the scene?

Comment: yeah, this seems to happen when I use Time.deltaTime * move... 
I'm thinking that needs to change to Time.deltaTime * speed instead or something similar maybe?

I've edited my post to include a photo of my scene and a short description of how the scene should work.

Comment: @EskiStoj are you mixing up the code? There's no `move` variable in the one I've presented. In fact, the code I've presented IS using `speed * Time.deltaTime`. 1sec, I'll test it and grab a gif.

Comment: @EskiStoj I've updated the answer with an animation showing the code performing what I think it is you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah you're right, my bad, your gif is exactly how i want it to work! it's just that I need all of the big cubes to move together, I've applied your script to a Parent GameObject of all of the big cubes;

Comment: I just noticed it's not enlarging the GameObject, also it doesn't seem to be stopping at the set destinations, but continues moving indefinitely, The GameObject's also moving closer to the camera, is there a way to maybe target the x axis specifically?

Comment: @EskiStoj is it just happening the first time? Where is your object starting? I suspect you might not be setting the object to the 'initial' starting position so it looks like it's moving on the other axes. You could add to `Awake` something like `transform.localPosition = _positions [ _positions.Count / 2 ];`

Comment: Hey thanks for the help so far, I've applied this to the Awake section, and now the gameobject only seems to be moving along the x axis, BUT it shifts my Big boxes well off the screen to the left and shifts them forward along the z axis haha, i think we're getting closer though, also the gameObject just keeps moving, it doesn't stop at it's set position..

Comment: i'm just wondering if there's something i'm not doing right in the inspector window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249414/discussion-between-milan-egon-votrubec-and-eski-stoj).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in using if statemen without loops like here

```
 if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 15000, mask))
        {
            
            if (hit.collider.tag == "1stBox"){
                ....
        }
       ......
      }
```

Make new variable `float dist;` and set it to be equal to distance between `transform.position` and destination point, like this:
`Vector3.Distance(transform.position, positionOne)` for first and so on.

after that use a While loop to check if distance is greater than 0.

Now your code will look like this:

```
float dist;
 if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 15000, mask))
        {
            
            if (hit.collider.tag == "1stBox"){
                dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, positionOne);
                while (dist > 0){
                      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionOne, move);
     
                }
        }
       ......
      }
```

**This code is NOT tested but should work**

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've just tried it out, and I'm receiving this error:
The name 'positionOne' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @EskiStoj I can't see why, you define it as a public field in the original code.

Comment: Ahhh I just noticed that I misspelled positionOne in my code, my bad, thank you again!!

Comment: So now that there's no more errors in the console, I tried to run the game a few times but each time i click on the trigger with that script attached to it Unity froze :/

Comment: I made a mistake, make sure to put calculating distance in while loop as well '''dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, positionOne);
                while (dist > 0){
                      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionOne, move);
 Vector3.Distance(transform.position, positionOne);    
                }''' and not only before loop.

Comment: The while loop would completely freeze the application

Comment: @derHugo I am aware of that i corrected myself please read all coments before posting.

Comment: @D4V3XX still makes no sense though ... `Vector3.Distance(transform.position, positionOne);` returns a `float` .. you don't do anything with it ... and it will still freeze this entire frame until the object reaches the position => For the user it will result in one longer frame and then the object snaps to the target position ...

Comment: Just tried this code and it works, moves slowly towards target.

Comment: Hey, I just applied the new part of the code and when i tested it, unfortunately Unity froze up again.

I'm wondering if there's a way to check the GameObject's position each frame with the '==' function? 
Would a bool returning false until it reaches the target location work? then set that to true once it hits the target location or visa-versa?